# Erlang: set node name that is persistent across host changes

Tags: erlang

I have a laptop that uses a VPN, and my hostname often changes. I get a different Erlang node name every time this happens. The docs for node (http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) do not seem to specify a way to set this statically.

How can I permanently configure my machine's nodename to be persistent across network changes?

Comment: Could `-sname` flag for the `erl` command work for you?

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga no because this doesn't get launched using `erl`. Is there a way to set this as an enviornmental variable?

Comment: How is it launched?

Comment: Through a rebar/relx release.

Comment: And sometimes during a common test using `rebar3 ct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rebar, you should have a `vm.args` somewhere and you can set the `-sname my_permanent_node_name` flag in here.

Note that no communication can exist between nodes running with flag -sname and those running with flag -name.

Comment: OK. This seems to work when I strait up execute the release using `./_build/....`. However, then I start the application using `rebar3 ct`, It still comes up with `noname@nohost`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Will still accept Asier's answer as it solved it for running normally.

Adding this because when running `rebar3 ct`, I hit this issue: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-March/088414.html. That is, `rebar3 ct` does not respect the `rebar.config` node name. I was able to solve this problem using an answer in that mailing thread:

```
set -x REBAR3_ERL_ARGS "-sname myapp@localhost"; rebar3 local install; env DEBUG=1 ~/.cache/rebar3/bin/rebar3 ct
```

So combined with these two answers I solved the problem.